# Problem parsing xml when retrieving from a URL

Tags: python, xml

I am doing an assignment from a Coursera Python course. The goal is to sum up the counts for each username and get a final tally.

XML: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml

If I copy and paste that XML and parse it with the following program, it works just fine.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

input = (XML string goes here)
ct = 0
stuff = ET.fromstring(input)
lst = stuff.findall('comments/comment')
for item in lst:
    print('Name', item.find('name').text)
    print('Count', item.find('count').text)
    ct = ct + int(item.find('count').text)
print(ct)
```

The problem is when I try to get it directly from the URL. In that case I have tried two approaches:

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

uh = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml')


data = uh.read()
print(data.decode())
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
lst = commentinfo.findall('comments/comment')   
for item in lst:
    print('Count', item.find('count').text)
```

This leads to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\patri\Desktop\PY4E\Materials\code3\urllib1.py", line 10, in <module>
    lst = commentinfo.findall('comments/comment')
NameError: name 'commentinfo' is not defined
```

Second approach is one that is suggested by the assignment, using the following way of accessing the counts:

```
counts = tree.findall('.//count')
```

And so I wrote the following code:

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

uh = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml')


data = uh.read()
print(data.decode())
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
counts = tree.findall('.//count')
for item in counts:
    print('Count', item.find('count').text)
```

This apparently leads to a None type and I cannot do anything with that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\patri\Desktop\PY4E\Materials\code3\urllib1.py", line 12, in <module>
    print('Count', item.find('count').text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: you use `commentinfo` which you didn't create - you should use `tree` instead of `commentinfo`

Comment: you should use `print()` to see what you get in `data`, `item`. MAybe you have XML without `count`

Answer (score 2):

In first code snippet the error is `NameError: name 'commentinfo' is not defined` due to the variable `commentinfo`, which isn't declared:

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

uh = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml')


data = uh.read()
print(data.decode())
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
# commentinfo not declared
lst = commentinfo.findall('comments/comment')   
for item in lst:
    print('Count', item.find('count').text)
```

Replace it with variable `tree` to make code work:

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

uh = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml')


data = uh.read()
print(data.decode())
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
lst = tree.findall('comments/comment')   
for item in lst:
    print('Count', item.find('count').text)
```

In second code snippet expression `tree.findall('.//count')` already gets a list of `count` elements. So when in the loop `item.find('count')` is called, it doesn't find a child named `count` inside the `count` element, leading to the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`. To fix it remove `item.find('count')` from the loop:

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse, urllib.error
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

uh = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml')


data = uh.read()
print(data.decode())
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
counts = tree.findall('.//count')
for item in counts:
    print('Count', item.text)
```